# SQL inspection/injection in Hibernate Reactive

Tags: java, spring-webflux, hibernate-reactive

Hibernate allows to inspect every SQL command and possibly returning a different SQL command before it is executed, thankfully to the [StatementInspector SPI](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/resource/jdbc/spi/StatementInspector.java).

In our (blocking) Spring Web App we are using it to implement multi-tenancy at row level. The user authenticates and in hibernate's `inspect` method we get user authentication info from the Spring `SecurityContextHolder`, which we use to change the SQL and implement multi-tenancy. Everything works, as each HTTP request is bound to a specify Thread that will completely fulfill the request.

In a reactive version of the above app this doesn't work. `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` returns the asynchronous type `Mono` and the hibernate's `inspect` method return a sync type (`String`).

Is there a similar method like `inspect` in hibernate reactive to keep the similar multitenancy implementation like in the blocking version, maybe something like `Mono<String> inspect(String sql);`

I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've created an issue](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues/1700) to keep track of this feature.

In the  meanwhile, in Hibernate Reactive, you could create a wrapper around `ReactiveConnection` and intercepts all the calls related to the execution of the query.

For example, you can have:

```java
public class ConnectionInterceptor implements ReactiveConnection {
   private final ReactiveConnection delegate;

   public ConnectionInterceptor(ReactiveConnection delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   public CompletionStage<Void> execute(String sql) {
       String newSql = convert(sql);
       return delegate.execute(newSql);
   }

   // ... You need to implement all the other methods running a query
}
```

```java
package my.example;

public class MyPool extends DefaultSqlClientPool {

   public CompletionStage<ReactiveConnection> getConnection() {
     return super.getConnection().thenApply( ConnectionInterceptor::new );
   }

}
```

You can register the new pool class using the property `hibernate.vertx.pool.class`:

```
hibernate.vertx.pool.class = my.example.MyPool
```